# how to register plugins to java registery

Tags: apache-servicemix, twelvemonkeys

How we can register any kind of plugin or **java libs** to **java registry**. I want to execute my application in *Apache service* mix and facing issue of unsupported image type. I have been using *TwelveMonkeys* libs but still facing same issue. As per *Twelvemonkeys* guidelines it is said that this *TwelveMonkeys* plugins are discovered automatically at run time, but its not the case when deploying project into service mix.

Any help would be great and thankful..

Comment: Late, but anyway... Here's a [blog post about registering ImageIO plugins in an OSGi container](http://betzelblog.blogspot.no/2017/03/twelvemonkeys-on-osgi.html), which might be helpful.